# How to embed an epub in a github pages website?

Tags: markdown, github-pages, pandoc, epub, epub.js

I am writing a book in markdown and converting it to pdf and epub using Pandoc. I am wondering if I can embed/view the epub in an HTML page on my GitHub pages website. I came across epub.js, but I am not able to figure out how I can use it on a GitHub pages website without installing it via node. I intend to generate a website for my book for example https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: see https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/#getting-started Or alternatively, use pandoc to output HTML instead of EPUB.

Answer (score 0):

You should also convert your markdown in a gitbook format, using [`gitbook.com`](https://www.gitbook.com/) (but that will publish it in a separate domain)

Or you might want to use a static content generator like **[Hugo](https://gohugo.io/)**, associated to a [theme like hugo-book](https://themes.gohugo.io/hugo-book/): you can then generate your book within your User GitHub page site.

Both solutions would be more doable than trying to include a foreign (non-HTML) format into GitHub pages.